# Continuation Passing Style in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, continuation-passing

I am a bit confused on the concept. So I have the following function

```
    let rec sumlist lst =
          match lst with
             | [] -> 0
             | (h::t) -> h + (sumlist t)
```

With continuation, it can be written as

```
let rec cont_sumlist lst c =
match lst with
| [] -> (c 0)
| (h::t) -> cont_sumlist t (fun x -> c (h + x))
```

I am still confused on what the `c` means and what it does

Comment: c is a function. `cont_sumlist l (fun x -> x)`  will return the sum of all list elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general answer is already given, but specifically, for `cont_sumlist`,

- in case of `[]` we "return" (i.e. feed) `0` *into* `c` that we're given (`0` *is* the sum of an empty list), and
- in case of `(h::t)` we construct the continuation for `cont_sumlist t` so that *after* the result for `t` (i.e. `x`) is ready, it will be combined with `h` (by `h + x`) and fed further into `c` given to us for `(h::t)`.

This is thus expressing the *equation* `sumlist (h::t) = h + sumlist t`, but the evaluation chain is made *explicit* as the chain of these continuation functions, each feeding its result to the continuation function above it; as opposed to being implicit in the stack-based evaluation mechanism.

In other words `fun x -> c (h + x)` = `c ∘ (h +)`, so as we go along the list `[h1; h2; h3; ...]`, the continuation is being progressively constructed as `c0 ∘ (h1 +) ∘ (h2 +) ∘ (h3 +) ∘ ...`, and is finally called with `0` when the list has been searched through completely; where `c0` is the top-most continuation given by a user to the top-most call, e.g.

```
cont_sumlist [1,2] (fun x -> x) 
= 
 (fun x -> (fun x -> (fun x -> x) (1 + x)) (2 + x)) 0
=
                     (fun x -> x) 
           (fun x ->              (1 + x)) 
 (fun x ->                                 (2 + x)) 0
=
                                  (1 +     (2 +     0))
```

So overall `cont_sumlist [x; y; z; ... ; n] c` turns into

```
 (c ∘ (x +) ∘ (y +) ∘ (z +) ∘ ... ∘ (n +) ) 0
= 
  c (x + (y + (z + .... + (n + 0) .... )))
```

with the crucial difference that there's no stack winding and unwinding involved and the sum is calculated from right to left directly, given in a C-like pseudocode as a sequence of simple steps

```c
    r = 0; 
    r += n; 
    .......
    r += z;
    r += y;
    r += x;
    call c(r);     // call c with r, without expecting c to return; like a jump
```

One might say that the construction of the overall continuation is similar to winding up the stack, and its application -- to the unwinding of the stack under conventional stack-based evaluation.

Another way of putting it is that CPS defines a special kind of function call protocol, unlike the usual C-like one which expects every function call to return.

Each case in the CPS definition can be interpreted as giving a small-step semantics transition rule for the function: `{ [] } --> 0 ; { (h::t) } --> h + { t }`.

Answer (score 6):

One way to look at continuation-passing style is to imagine how you would write code if functions weren't allowed to return. You could still make things work by having an extra parameter of each function that tells what you want to do after the function does its computation. I.e., you pass a function that acts as a "continuation" of the overall computation.

The code you give is written exactly this way, and `c` is the continuation. I.e., it's a function that the caller passes in that tells what to do next after the function does its intended calculation.

Continuation-passing style is completely general, i.e., all computations can be expressed this way. And, in fact, there's a mechanical transformation from ordinary functional code into continuation-passing style.